How to find the lowest "latest version" of Google Chrome
Before 2023, this was an easy question to answer. Google hosted a JSON at Omahaproxy (https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/json) which would give a simple response when queried.
Asking...
(Invoke-WebRequest 'https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/json' | ConvertFrom-Json | select -expand versions | ? {$_.os -eq 'win' -and $_.channel -eq 'stable'}).version

...would produce a response 123.4.5.678.
After 2023 and the deprecation of Omahaproxy, Chrome versions became hugely splintered, and there was no longer a single source of truth for what version was being served.
The following shows the outcome of four different checks for the "latest version" of Chrome, performed at 2:30PM on the 10th of May 2024 in London, UK (with PowerShell, where appropriate):

($(irm 'https://versionhistory.googleapis.com/v1/chrome/platforms/win64/channels/stable/versions').versions | select -first 1).version

125.0.6422.41


($(irm 'https://versionhistory.googleapis.com/v1/chrome/platforms/win64/channels/stable/versions/all/releases?filter=fraction=1').releases | select -first 1).version

124.0.6367.119


"Latest version" reading on https://chromeenterprise.google/intl/en_uk/browser/download/#windows-tab

124.0.6367.201


Actually downloading the MSI and checking the "comment" field for the version

124.0.6367.202



Recently my strategy has been to monitor the API for any sort of big change and then to do a few downloads of the MSI a few hours apart to see what version number it standardises on, but recently I've seen issues where the version number I download differs from the version number other people across the world will download, even though we are using the same link.
It would appear as if different versions are being served based on geographical location.
This splintering of Chrome versions across groups and regions – apparently there are four different "latest" versions – appears to be a deliberate action by Google but it makes it almost impossible for administrators to get a solid answer to the question of what version the line of compliance should be drawn at.
The problem is not that any of the different answers are not valid – since different regions and groups are receiving different versions, all answers can be considered valid. Instead, the question administrators need to ask is "what is the lowest 'latest version' of Google Chrome being served publicly".
With this, we can wait until the very last group has begun receiving this version and update our documentation accordingly. If users receive a later version than the "latest" in the meantime, so be it.
Is there a simple source for this information? The obvious answer is just to gather as many disparate "latest version" figures as possible and pick the lowest one, but this feels like such a messy solution to a problem that should be simple to solve.
(Reminder: I am not looking to litigate the backend system powering this requirement; it is what it is. I need an answer to the question and not a debate around its validity.)
